# SharePoint Online Modern auto expand quick launch via spfx

Tags: spfx, modern-experience, quick-launch, modern-team-site

Has anyone figured out how this company was able to achieve the auto expand the quick launch via spfx? https://www.tecconsult.at/products/sharepoint-auto-expand-left-navigation/

I can't seem to figure out how to simulate the onlick event via spfx.  In the dom there's zero difference between Inventory (with sub items) and Documents (without)

[image]

**BEFORE**

[image: Before Clicking]

**AFTER**

[image: After Clicking]

Answer (score 0):

This element has the `onClick` event for expanding the menu item:

```html
<button type="button" class="ms-Button ms-Nav-link ms-Button--action ms-Button--command link-271" title="Directorate Structure" aria-describedby="id__46" data-is-focusable="true" tabindex="0">
...
</button>
```

It is placed inside the `<div class="ms-Nav-compositeLink">` element of the menu list.

If the menu item is expandable it renders as `<button>`, not a link `<a>` element. So, you can somehow select and filter it from the DOM by the SPFX extension (placeholders from Application Customizer), I suppose. Example:

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.ms-Nav-navItems');
const button = menu.querySelectorAll('.ms-Nav-compositeLink button.ms-Nav-link');
button[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wanders in, here's how you do it (@Dm s has it 95% with quick suedo code).

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.ms-Nav-navItems');
const button = menu.querySelectorAll('.ms-Nav-compositeLink > button.ms-Nav-chevronButton');
button[0].click();
```